# How do i create multiple boxplots in the same figure using pivot long data?

Tags: r, boxplot

I created a data frame called "Pivot_long" by using the pivot_longer function to combine 3 variables from another dataset ("Leaves") into one column. Now i need to create a a figure with multiple boxplots to display this "Pivot_long" data. How would i go about doing that?
Formula for the new data frame:

```r
Pivot_long<- pivot_longer(data = Leaves, names_to = "Type", values_to = "Values", cols = -X)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how to visualize 4 plots next to eachother?
The setting par() allows for combining multiple plots.

```r
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
```

Run this before your plot() function, and this will create a 2x2 matrix with 4 seperate plots.

Comment: (1) `par(mfrow=.)` needs multiple calls to base-graphics plot functions, not just one plot call. If there is just one call to `plot()`, then (2) this doesn't apply, since the question is how to show multiple boxes/whiskers with long-form pivoted data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example with the iris data set:

```
library(tidyverse)
iris_long <- iris %>% 
    select(-4, -5) %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        cols = everything()
    )

ggplot(iris_long, aes(x = name, y=value)) +
    geom_boxplot()
```

[image]